# Core plot objective-c, graph having single plot is not automatically scaling even using [graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]]

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-plot

Core plot Objective-C, graph having single plot is not automatically scaling even using `[graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]]`. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the plot belongs to the default plot space. In other words, use `-addPlot:` instead of creating a new plot space and using `-addPlot:toPlotSpace:`.